# How is species of pet legalized?

Tags: united-states, regulations, pets

I understand the environmental impacts of taking a species from one place to another.

How can I legalize to have a native species as a new pet like a cat or dog? For example, you can get canned opossum to eat, they been around since the dinosaurs and are not endangered. I have a rehabilitation license and it is easy but how do I petition or start a bill to make it easy and legal for everyone without a license to receive a pet opossum?

Comment: Call your Congress-critter. And since your question is about legislating laws and not current laws or legal theory, you're better off asking on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm guessing that there's no national law about making opossums pets. State and/or local law would likely apply, but the process you'd have to go through may depend on the state - perhaps there's an executive agency that rules on such things, or perhaps there's a specific law. Narrowing down which state you're talking about may help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about political processes and action, not legal process or the law itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Petitions and the like are outside the scope of this site. But the first step, which *is* in the scope of this site, is to know what law you want to change. This is likely going to depend on the animal and the state, and possibly local laws as well.

For example, Wisconsin law makes it illegal to possess a "wild animal" under most circumstances without a license. However, there is already an [exception](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/169.04(4)(a)7.) for opossums, among other animals.

Under Wisconsin law, "Wild animal" is defined as "any animal of a wild nature that is normally found in the wild and that is not a domestic animal". "Domestic animal", in turn, is defined as "a farm-raised deer, a pet bird, a farm-raised game bird, or an animal that is listed as a domestic animal by rule by the department of agriculture, trade and consumer protection." So, presumably, you'd have two choices if you wanted to legalize an animal not currently exempted: you could get the state legislature to add an exception to the law, or you could get the department of agriculture, trade and consumer protection to modify their rules to get it defined as a domestic animal.